# assembly x86 test si

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

What is the meaning of the following code?

```
mov si, [L10003248]
test si, si
jnz L10004356
```

I think it means jump to `L10004356` if `L10003248` address is not null. I think it does not relate to value stored in `L10003248` otherwise it had used `word ptr`.

Is my assumption correct?

It does not sound logical. Since this jump looks trivial.

I have no information about the compiler.

Comment: It **does** relate to the value stored at `L10003248`. You seem to misunderstand `ptr`: http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0250_ptr_pointer.htm

Comment: @cad Please make it the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov si, [L10003248]
```

**does** relate to the memory location **at** `L10003248`, not just the address. That's uniquely indicated by the square brackets.

> [...] otherwise it had used word ptr [...]

No, `word ptr` doesn't indicate a memory location but the **size** of the memory location.

Take the instruction

```
mov [eax], 12h
```

Now, the assembler can guess what the size of `12h` is. Is it 16 bit (`0012h`)? Or 8 bit (`12h`)? That needs to be passed as information to the assembler. Here, the `ptr` directive comes into play:

```
mov word ptr [eax], 12h
```

Now, the assembler unambigously knows that 16 bit of data have to copied. Similarly, `byte ptr` and `dword ptr` could've been added. For further information on the `ptr` directive, read [this](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/I77_0250_ptr_pointer.htm).

---

Another case can be

```
mov [16_bit_mem], 12h
```

Some assemblers (like MASM) memorize the size of a variable, so this instruction compiles fine. OTOH, some (like NASM and GNU as) don't. In NASM, you need to write

```
mov word ptr [16_bit_mem], 12h
```

to provide the size of the data to the assembler. GNU as uses the AT&T syntax by default (as opposed to the Intel syntax used by MASM and NASM). Here, you append a suffix (`b` for `byte`, `w`, for `word`, `l` for `long`, and `q` for `quadword`) to the mnemonic instead of the `ptr` directive:

```
movw 0x12, (16_bit_mem)
```

That's in AT&T syntax, of course (source and destination operands, swapped, `0x` instead of `h`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

[L10003248] means *L10003248, it's the value stored in address L10003248.

So your code actually means:

```
si = *L10003248;
if (si != 0)
    jmp L10004356
```